# Move JavaScript methods into global scope

Tags: javascript, function

In JavaScript, is it possible to move inner functions from one function into the global scope? I haven't yet found any straightforward way to do this.

```
function moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope(functionName){
    //move all of functionName's methods into the global scope
    //methodsToPutIntoGlobalScope should be used as the input for this function.
}

//I want all of the methods in this function to be moved into the global scope so that they can be called outside this function.
function methodsToPutInGlobalScope(){
    function alertSomething(){
        alert("This should be moved into the global scope, so that it can be called from outside the function that encloses it.");
    }
    function alertSomethingElse(){
        alert("This should also be moved into the global scope.");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not possible this way, you can make `methodsToPutInGlobalScope` an object instead of function and then you will be able to access functions inside it.

Comment: Does `methodsToPutInGlobalScope` only have function declarations inside it, or is there more? For example, using eval *could* work, but might not be what you want if there are more than function declarations inside the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to make changes in `methodsToPutInGLobalSpace` you can use the following dirty hack:

```
var parts = methodsToPutInGlobalScope.toString().split('\n');
eval(parts.splice(1, parts.length - 2).join(''));
```

As final solution we can use:

```
moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope(methodsToPutInGlobalScope);
alertSomething(); //why doesn't this work?

function moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope(functionName){
    var parts = functionName.toString().split('\n');
    eval.call(window, parts.splice(1, parts.length - 2).join(''));  
}

//I want all of the methods in this function to be moved into the global scope so that they can be called outside this function.
function methodsToPutInGlobalScope(){
    function alertSomething(){
        alert("This should be moved into the global scope, so that it can be called from outside the function that encloses it.");
    }
    function alertSomethingElse(){
        alert("This should also be moved into the global scope.");
    }
}
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/5CC52/2/)

Comment: This answer still doesn't explain how to implement `moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope`, which is what I was trying to do in the first place.

Comment: There's no trivial way to do this. I guess you need to parse `moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope` (use `moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope.toString()` to get the string representation) and after that declare the inner functions in the global scope.

Comment: Done! You can see the changes.

Comment: Have you tested this solution yet? I couldn't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/5CC52/1/ It produces this error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: alertSomething is not defined`

Comment: I like it, but there are some `Function.prototype.toString` gotchas to be wary of - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3379880/319878.

Comment: I've noticed that pre-existing functions aren't being replaced in the global scope. Is there any way to work around this problem? http://jsfiddle.net/5CC52/5/

Comment: Actually they are replaced but in jsfiddle everything is wrapped inside a function look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/5CC52/6/

Comment: @MinkoGechev Hm. Would it be possible to replace each original function inside `moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope`?

Comment: What do you mean with that? Each function declared in `moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope` is being defined as global and replaces any other function with the same name. The issue in JSFiddle was not because of the solution but because `alertSomething` (not the one declared at `moveMethodsIntoGlobalScope`) was declared in the local scope of the `onload` function.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sophisticated, but would work.

```
function copyInto(arr, context) {
    //move all of functionName's methods into the global scope
    //methodsToPutIntoGlobalScope should be used as the input for this function.
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 2) {
        var exportName = arr[i];
        var value = arr[i + 1];
        eval(exportName + "=" + value.toString());
    }
}

//I want all of the methods in this function to be moved into the global scope so that they can be called outside this function.
function methodsToPutInGlobalScope() {
    function alertSomething() {
        alert("This should be moved into the global scope, so that it can be called from outside the function that encloses it.");
    }

    function alertSomethingElse() {
        alert("This should also be moved into the global scope.");
    }

    copyInto(["alertSomething", alertSomething, "alertSomethingElse", alertSomethingElse], window);
}

methodsToPutInGlobalScope();
alertSomething();
alertSomethingElse();
```

Comment: When `methodsToPutIntoGlobalScope` is called, it appears that it doesn't overwrite pre-existing functions. Is there any way to work around this problem? http://jsfiddle.net/5CC52/9/

Comment: Strange. This will work `window["alertSomething"]();`. Looks like the method call is bound to the original, but an indirect method call will work.

Comment: It works with `eval`, like the answer from @Minko Gechev - http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/5CC52/12/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is **possible**. If you declare a variable using `var` keyword that variable becomes local only, but if you don't it becomes a global one.

```
function foo(){

   var test = 'test'; // <- Using var keyword
}

foo(); // <- execute the function

console.log(test); // undefined
```

But if we do the same thing without `var` keyword:

```
function foo(){

   test = 'test'; // <- Using var keyword
}

foo(); // <- execute the function

console.log(test); // test
```

In order to make your inner functions global, you'd declare **anonymous functions** without `var` keyword

```
function methodsToPutInGlobalScope() {

    alertSomething = function () {
        alert("This should be moved into the global scope, so that it can be called from outside the function that encloses it.");
    }

    alertSomethingElse = function () {
        alert("This should also be moved into the global scope.");
    }

}


methodsToPutInGlobalScope(); // <- Don't forget to execute this function


alertSomething(); // Works
alertSomethingElse(); // Works as well
```