# Insert a line into a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

In JavaScript, is it possible to insert a line into a function that already exists? I want to create a function that inserts a line at a specific position in a function:

```
function insertLine(theFunction, lineToInsert, positionToInsert){
    //insert a line into the function after the specified line number       
}
```

For example, would it be possible to programmatically insert the line `checkParameterTypes(min, "string", max, "string");` before the first line of this function?

```
function getRandomInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: I really doubt if you can "insert" lines into a function. But, surely, you can wrap that function inside another one that calls your `checkParameterTypes(..)` before invoking `getRandomInteger(..)`.

Comment: @Thrustmaster, You definitely *can* insert a line by getting the function's code, putting one in, and redefining it.  But why would you want to?  Duck punching, as you have proposed, is the way to do this.

Comment: @Brad The `eval`/`Function` constructor would evaluate it in the global scope though, losing access to all local variables. Sure it may suffice for some use cases, but is not ideal.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, Ah, true enough.  In any case, it isn't something you want to do.  :-D

Comment: @Brad Yeah `=]` And then debugging a function made from a string evaluated in the global scope is terrible beyond any necessity. `:P`

Comment: @Brad Agreed, but string substitution and eval to achieve this kind of behaviour, really?! I wouldn't want to live with such lines of code! :P

Comment: @FabrícioMatté What do you mean "evaluate it in the global scope"? I don't think it does. Are you thinking of `setTimeout`?

Comment: @Ian what I meant was its variable scope. http://jsfiddle.net/mNF2j/

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Ahh, I think that's special/only with the `Function` constructor (and I didn't know that). If you look at http://jsfiddle.net/mNF2j/2/ , you'll see the `eval` knows about `privateVar`, but you're obviously right about `Function`. At the same time, technically, you could set it up to accept parameters and stuff, but that's not important.

Comment: @Ian You're right, eval [keeps the variable context](http://jsfiddle.net/mNF2j/3/). Interesting indeed. As the Function constructor is considered an alias for `eval`, I expected it to have the same scoping behavior but it doesn't. Learned something new today (though we usually tend to avoid using `eval` `:P`). Of course in case of using the Function constructor one can adapt it to accept parameters but that's rather cumbersome. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yep, I learned about `Function`'s scope today, so we all learned :) But yeah, I'd avoid both, and you're right that it's cumbersome, I just wanted to point it out that it *could* be done to access local variables. Either way, the accepted answer here seems good and doesn't use either :)

Comment: In order to implement something like this, I'd probably need to [convert a function's string representation into a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573548/given-a-string-describing-a-javascript-function-convert-it-to-a-javascript-func).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want something to happen at the beginning of a function, you can use the following. You do have access to `this` and the arguments from your injected function. So it will still work for functions that require a specific context.

```
function inject(before, fn) {
    return function(){
        before.apply(this, arguments);
        return fn.apply (this, arguments);
    }
}
```

For example

```
function add(a, b) {
   return a + b; 
}    

function concat(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

/**
 * You can repeat index and type to check multiple arguments
 */
function createArgumentChecker(index, type /**index, type, ... */) {
    var originalArgs = arguments; 
    return function() {
        for (var i=0; i < originalArgs.length; i+=2) {
             var index = originalArgs[i],
                 requestedType = originalArgs[i+1],
                 actualType = typeof arguments[index];
             if (typeAtIndex  != actualType) {
                 console.log("Invalid argument passed at index " + index  + 
                     ". Expected type " + requestedType +  "but it's " + actualType );
             }
        }
    }
}

function logArguments() {
    console.log(this, arguments);
}

// Inject an argument checker
add = inject(add, createArgumentChecker(0,"number", 1, "number"));
concat = inject (concat, createArgumentChecker(0, "string", 1, "string"));

// You can even do it multiple times, inject an argument logger;
add = inject(add, logArguments);
concat = inject(concat, logArguments);
```

*[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sDBJ9/)*

This can be handy when debugging websites that you can't modify the source code, I wouldn't use it do parameter checking unless you can strip it our for the production version.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but using eval is always evil ;)

```
function insertInbetween (arr, value, index) {
  var inserted, i, newarr = [];
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(i == index && !inserted) {
      newarr[i] = value;
      inserted = true;
    }
    newarr.push(arr[i]);
  }
  return newarr;
}

function test (a, b) {
    console.log(a,b);
}

var fstrarr = test.toString().split('\n');
eval(insertInbetween(fstrarr, "console.log('injected!');", 1).join('\n'));
```

Edit:
As mentioned in the comments to your question you'll loose scope by doing so.