# JavaScript - pass string variable to eval

Tags: javascript, eval

Part of code my generates a string, which is then suppose to be used by a function to generated a chuck in VoxelJS.

An example string is "(y == 1)? 1 : 0"

Which I then need to be added to a function like this, eg. "function(x, y, z){return (y == 1)? 1 : 0}"

I thought using eval would change my string to the needed code, like this:

```
gtest = function(x, y, z){return eval(generationString) };
```

but I misunderstood how eval is used, and realized I needed to try something else.

If I look at `gtest` in the JavaScript console it says it's structure is `function (x, y, z){return eval(generationString) }` when I want it to look like `function (x, y, z){return return (y == 1)? 1 : 0}}`. Attempting to pass the code containting the eval causes VoxelJS to crash/freeze when it tries to generate new chunks.

How can I convert the string with the javascript code to code in a function in the way I want?

I realize this might be a hard to understand question, sorry about that, I'm not sure how to describe it any other way.

Comment: Your `eval` function should have worked, unless `eval` is not `eval`. Of course, it's potentially slow if that function is called *very* often.

Comment: @Bergi yeah it was being called hundreds of times a second, so it was probably just extremely slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer literally 30 seconds after posting this, use the function() constructor.

[Given a string describing a Javascript function, convert it to a Javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573548/given-a-string-describing-a-javascript-function-convert-it-to-a-javascript-func)

```
gtest = new Function('x', 'y', 'z', 'return ' + generationString);
```