# when the alert() in string , how to convert it as a function to show the alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

When an `alert()` method is in double quotes it  behaves like a string, meaning when it is printed in the console, the console screen shows the `alert()`. But i want, when there is an `alert()` in `console.log()`, to show an alert box. I have written the following piece of code but it does not fulfill my requirements:

```
var msg="alert("welcome")"
console.log(msg)
```

When I run the above code, the output to the console is `alert("welcome")` and no alert box is created. Could anyone help me figure out how to show an alert box?

Thanks

Comment: look to the eval. But this is bad idea to use both of them without serious reason

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2573556/3840037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `eval()` function:

> The eval() function evaluates or executes an argument.
>
> If the argument is an expression, eval() evaluates the expression. If
>   the argument is one or more JavaScript statements, eval() executes the
>   statements.

```js
var msg = "alert(\"welcome\")"; // Sample message.
console.log(msg);             // Log to the console regardless.
eval(msg);                    // Evaluate the message as an expression.
// Alternatively, regarding your comment about the message being altered, you can do one of the following:
var msg = "alert('welcome')";
console.log(msg);
eval(msg); 
// Or:
var msg = 'alert("welcome")';
console.log(msg);
eval(msg); 
// Or even:
var msg = 'alert(\'welcome\')';
console.log(msg);
eval(msg);
```

Comment: Thanks@Angelos Chalaris , for reply but we can't change the string format means in **msg**  we can't insert **\** in to the msg

Comment: I did not insert anything in the message. In fact all I did was escape the quotations in order not to terminate the string so that it is not `"alert("` `welcome` `")"` but instead `alert("welcome")`. Alternatively, you can do `var msg='alert("welcome")'` or `var msg="alert('welcome')"` with the same result. - **EDIT:** @Debasish check the code now with more possible variations of how you can make a valid `msg` that contains quotes.

Comment: Thanks@Angelos Chalaris , it is working for me and solve my problem , thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do two things, you need code to do two things. If you want to do two things with one statement, you need to make a function that does both things for you.

```
function doubleAlert(msg) {
  console.log(msg);
  alert(msg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks@Erik , but you can't understand my problem , i want a alert box which contain only **welcome** , when i call the **msg** in consol.log , means simultaneously the inner code will be execute .

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function alertAndConsole(msg){
    alert(msg);
    return msg;
}
console.log(alertAndConsole("WELCOME"))
```