# Javascript for a prompt which accepts simple math as a value and then returns the answer

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript)

I have written a snippet of code in javascript, for a prompt to appear when clicked. I want to be able to enter a simple math problem (i.e. 230/2) and have it output the answer, rather than the math problem I just entered. Your help will be much appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var x;

var mathProblem=prompt("Enter your math problem","");

if (name!=null)
  {
  x = mathProblem;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's `name` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval()` to **compute** it:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = eval(x);
```

Here is how your code should be:

```
function myFunction()
{
  var mathProblem = prompt("Enter your math problem","");

  if (mathProblem)
  {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = eval(mathProblem);
  }
}
```

Or if you dont want to use `eval()` (not recommended usually), you can create small functions to do the computation like for adding, dividing, etc

Comment: And what if the user starts typing `<script>alert("I am evil");</script>` in the prompt?

Comment: It would also be possible to restrict `mathProblem` to containing only digits and valid maths operators, which may be sufficient in this trivial example.

Comment: You are right, it really depends on the complexity of the allowed input here. If it's only about simple adding, substracting, dividing or multiplying it should be fine to parse the input in a regex to remove unsafe characters.