# Split a string and do addition, multiplication etc

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a string like `10+20*30-40/2`. Is it possible to split this string and do calculations like `+` for addition, or `*` for multiplication?

Comment: It's possible. What part of it do you struggle with?

Comment: I would like to split the sting and do addition multiplication etc.May i know how to proceed for this?

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript

Comment: I would like to do multiplication ,division etc too

Comment: Will the string always be in this format?

Comment: Not really it can differ based on the user input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this very easily with the `eval` function...

```
var answer = eval("10+20*30-40/2");
alert(answer);
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/m42qQ/)

But you should be careful, because if you are accepting user input for this string then it could be malicious.

Comment: Thank you for your response.I would like to split the sting and do this.Like + for addition * for multiplication etc

Comment: @dddddd: I think if you want manual parsing, then you question is to broad as it currently stands. You need to try some stuff and come back with more specific questions/problems. [Here is an interesting article](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/) that might help, it's not in javascript and I haven't read it, but it looks like it could be useful in explaining the process