# Display 3+4-2 as 5 using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a `input field` where user can write equation like **3+4-2** etc.
Using `jquery` I can retrieve the value of input field like this:

```
var eqn = $("input").val();
```

Variable `eqn` contain **3+4-2**, I have to display it as **5**(by solving) not as **3+4-2**. How to display the equation as result?
Equation may contain the symbols `+,-,*,/,.` etc.

Since the variable `eqn` is `string type` it display as **3+4-2**. When I use `parseFloat` it display as **3**. So this can't be use.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas, I am asking a jquery solution

Comment: That doesn't make much sense; jQuery is a DOM manipulation library, it can't help you with this.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some research in the related question: [Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript)

There appears to be a locked-down version of the javascript 'eval' method which exposes the maths functionality but not the entire JS API to a user in the [mathjs](http://mathjs.org/) library. Which allows statements like this:

```
math.eval('1.2 * (2 + 4.5)');
```

Answer (score -3):

Write code using eval

eval('3+4-2')

Comment: This would be a very insecure way of handling user input. Which could easily break the application. Fortunately, client-side javascript rarely has access to a file system, OS or other applications which could do any real harm, and all attacks of this type could be attempted from a browser console.

Comment: I think You're missing @AJFaraday 's point...  You should at least investigate if that function protects against things it shouldn't be allowed to do.

Comment: The basic concern here is what else you can do with it, because you're evaluating javascript here, not just the mathematical functions. Try typing this... "alert('this is not secure')"

Comment: 2.1+3.2 gives 5.300000000000001, but expected is 5.3

Comment: He already did, see the second comment to your question. As for the floating point issue see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: I think there may have been some confusion here with a floating point issue in javascript. I'm putting in a suggested answer.