# How to convert String into Math Function just once?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to build something similar to desmos, where you can draw a graph in a canvas and then move it around.

I've been successful so far, but the only thing left is the user input.

Using a `<input type="text">` tag I want the user to write for example:

```
"5x + 2"
```

The result should be:

```
var f = 5*x + 2;
```

I searched a lot for a way to do this and the only things I found were some Maths libraries in JavaScript and the `eval()` function. The last one is really helpful, because I could replace the `x` with the `x` value in the graph and it would work to build the graph of the function. The problem is that it lags a lot when I want to move the graph around so it is not the best idea.

I'm sure that it lags because the `eval()` function has to convert the string each time for every x value of the canvas for about 40-50 times a second.

What I want to achieve is convert the string into a Math function just once, and then use it.

Is it possible? Can anyone please help

**EDIT 1**:
This is my function:

```
function f (pixelX) {
    var x = getCoordX (pixelX);

    var f = 2 * x + 2;

    return getPixelY(f);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it to be converted 40-50 times a second? The problem is not with `eval`. You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript)

Comment: @Cristy When I move the mouse, the coordinate system moves as well. I measured it with a count variable that it is about 50 times a second

Comment: Yes, the question is how you re-draw the canvas. The eval is instant, the problem is the time it takes to redraw the canvas, that's why it lags. Try calling your `draw` function inside a  `requestAnimationFrame` callback.

Comment: [mathJS](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) does exactly what you need with its parsing engine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question (even though this won't solve your problem).

You can do this.

```
var myString = "5 * x + 2";
var f = Function("x", "return " + myString);
```

This creates a `function` from a `string`. The first argument is the name of the first parameter, `x`, and the second argument is the body of the function (the `return` statement);

And then you can call it like: 
`f(3)` and the result would be `17`.

Note that you have to write multiplication in your equation like `5 * x` not like `5x`.

This way you only evaluate the string into a function once, and then you can call it as many times you want with different parameters.

Your problem is not that `eval` takes a long time to compute but that re-drawing the canvas is very expensive. Try limiting the number of draws or only calling the draw function inside a `requestAnimationFrame` callback, this way the browser will redraw the canvas only when it is ready to do it.

Comment: The canvas redraws only when the mousebutton is pressed the the mouse is moved. I haven't yet limited the number of draws, and I didn't know anything about `requestAnimationFrame`. I will see if your example works.

Comment: It did work, and it worked much better than `eval()`. _This way you only evaluate the string into a function once, and then you can call it as many times you want with different parameters._ That is what I was looking for. I will look more deeply into this `requestAnimationFrame`. Thanks a lot. Will upvote and mark your answer as the right one. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use eval, but it may behave differently on each browser's JavaScript engine.

This is an easy find-and-replace:

```js
function solveForX(equation, xValue) {
  var expanded = equation.replace(/(\d+(?:\.\d+|))x/g, '$1 * x');
  return eval(expanded.replace(/x/g, xValue));
}

console.log(solveForX("5x + 2", 3));       // 17
console.log(solveForX("-4.2x + 3x", 5));   // -6
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

### Advanced — Multi-variable Expressions

```js
const expFormat = '(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+|)){{@}}';
var expressionCache = {};
function lookupExpansion(v) {
  if (!expressionCache[v]) {
    expressionCache[v] = new RegExp(expFormat.replace(/\{\{\@\}\}/, v), 'g');
  }
  return expressionCache[v];
}

function toFunction(equation, variables) {
  variables.forEach(variable => {
    equation = equation.replace(lookupExpansion(variable), '$1 * ' + variable);
  });
  equation = equation.replace(/\b([a-z])([a-z])\b/g, '$1 * $2');
  console.log('[DEBUG]: Expanded => ' + equation);
  return Function.apply(null, variables.concat('return ' + equation));
}

// ======================== Simple ============================== //
var simpleMultiVariableFn = toFunction("x + 4x + 2y", ['x', 'y']);
console.log(simpleMultiVariableFn(3, 5)); // 25

// ======================== Advanced ============================ //
var slopeInterceptFunction = (slope, yIntercept) => {
  return x => toFunction("mx + b", ['m', 'x', 'b']).call(null, slope, x, yIntercept);
};
var interceptFn = slopeInterceptFunction(1, 2); // Reusable!
console.log(interceptFn(3)); // 5
console.log(interceptFn(4)); // 6
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Works with floats and negative numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will look into this more deeply later. ;)