# Invoke script written in Java from Java source code

Tags: java, java-8

I am aware of the Java Scripting API (which runs scripts written in JavaScript, Groovy etc) and several expression languages (SpEL, JEXL, JUL). But it is possible to write scripts in Java itself and then invoke that script from Java code?

I found some information on compiling Java programmatically via the [tools API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) but this not like scripting (i.e. the context is different).

I imagine something like this script being executed by my Java code:

```
int i = 42 + getFoo();
setBar(i);
```

Now - when invoked with a context that provides `getFoo` and `setBar` methods - it should evaluate `i` and call the method.

Comment: So you're looking for a REPL like JShell?

Comment: JSell could be an option for Java 9 but I'm fixed on Java 8. The alternative BeanShell feels outdated (from 2005?). As long as JShell scripts can be called from Java it would serve my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html#Calling_BeanShell_From_Your_Application) or the [Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/ToolProvider.html) or [javax.script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html) ...

one either has to interpret the text input or compile to byte-code, somehow.

Comment: https://code.google.com/archive/p/beanshell2/ & https://github.com/pejobo/beanshell2

Comment: It feels like BeanShell is out of date, isn't it?

Comment: see the link for beanshell2... javax.script might be the suggested method, while it can interpret Java code. it depends what that file might contain - because writing a simple parser should be no problem.

Comment: Ok, I wonder how I can interpret Java code with javax.script? As far as I know JavaScript, Groovy etc are available but I didn't read that Java syntax itself is supported. Do you know how it works?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html ...there are several engines, while one can create custom engines. at least there's `importPackage()` & 
`importClass()`.

Comment: based upon the input below, I have found the `Expression Language 3.0 specification, JSR341` - see `javax.el` https://github.com/javaee/el-spec/tree/master/api/src/main/java/javax/el and `commons-jexl` http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/ ... which both seem to be leaning towards enabling the web-scripting.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [exp4j](http://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/)'s nice API. Also check out other options at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41532702/37020

Comment: exp4j seems to be like the mentioned expression languages but I really need scripting with short code blocks, multiple statements etc.