# Check if string is a mathematical expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to know an easy way of checking if a string is a mathematical expression.
As an example, Google (and other search engines) use this when you search.

**PS**: I don't necessarily want to check stuff like `sin`, `cos`, etc.

Example: `2+2` should return `true` but `letters+somethingelse` should return `false`

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: maybe try converting the result to int, if that fails return false.

Comment: @void I have a string, str, equal to an input's value through document.getElementById

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a regex that can do what I think you're looking for:

```
/(?:(?:^|[-+_*/])(?:\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?\s*))+$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/w74GSk/4

It matches a   number, optionally negative, with an optional decimal number followed by zero or more operator/number pairs.

It also allows for whitespace between numbers and operators.

```js
const re = /(?:(?:^|[-+_*/])(?:\s*-?\d+(\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?\s*))+$/;

function test(s) {
  console.log("%s is valid? %s", s, re.test(s));
}

// valid
test(" 1 ");
test("1 + 2");
test(" 1 * 2 * 3 ");
test("-1 * 2 - -3");
test("-1 * 2 - -3e4");
test("-1 * 2 - -3.5E6");

// invalid
test("1 +");
test("1 + foo");
```

This may need to be expanded, based on what you want to allow. One thing it does not handle is parentheses to override operator precedence.

Comment: not that the question is asking for it but for anyone else, this doesn't account for the number e so beware of that edge case

Comment: @floor: You're right. There's a good bit that this doesn't handle. Just a simple starting point I guess.

Comment: @floor `\d+\.?\d*(?:e[+-]?\d+)?` is a good regex to match all valid numeric constants

Comment: I updated the regex to avoid repeating the definition of the number, and to include and expand upon @PatrickRoberts notation so that it allows capital `E` and prohibits a trailing `.` to avoid `3.e4`, though that's a matter of opinion.

Comment: Not a big deal, but `[eE]` can be `e` if you specify the case-`i`nsensitive flag at the end of the regex literal.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`complex-js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/complex-js), you can wrap [`Complex.compile()`](https://github.com/patrickroberts/complex-js#compile) in a `try/catch` statement:

```js
function isMathExpression (str) {
  try {
    Complex.compile(str);
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
  
  return true;
}

console.log(isMathExpression('2+2'))
console.log(isMathExpression('foo+bar'))
console.log(isMathExpression('sin(5)+sqrt(2/5i)'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/complex-js@5.0.0/dst/complex.min.js"></script>
```

The grammar for this parser is [here](https://github.com/patrickroberts/complex-js/blob/master/compiler/grammar.ne#L36-L121), if you're interested in seeing what constructs it supports.

<sub>Full disclosure, I am the author of this library</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can use math.js for this.

For your case use
`math.evaluate(expression)`

If you want to check whether an expression(containing variables) is mathematically valid use `math.parse(expression)` E.g. `math.parse('a+b')` is valid but `math.parse('b+')` will throw an exception.

```
function isValidMathExpression(expr){
        try{
            math.parse(expr);
            return true;
        }
        catch(ex){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). Go to that link to learn more about them.

This is a very simple example that just checks for a number and then a +, -, *, or / and then another number. You will want to adjust it and add to it to suit your needs.

```
/\d+(\+|\-|\*|\/)\d+/.test("1+2") // returns true
/\d+(\+|\-|\*|\/)\d+/.test("a+b") // returns false
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `eval(expression)` to execute it, and you need to use "trycatch" to wrap the code block. if it catches an error, the expression should be invalid