# Js - Alternatives to eval mathematical expression with operator as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, eval

I have a library that have the feature of filtering objects based on some fields (each field has a specific kind of type - more info on https://github.com/jy95/mediaScan/wiki )

The biggest problem is to handle number properties from multiple source

```
// to handle number operations
export interface NumberExpressionObject {
    operator: "==" | ">" | "<" | ">=" | "<=";
    number: number;
}

// additional Properties
export interface AdditionalProperties {
    type: AdditionalPropertiesType;
    name: string;
    value: boolean | string | string[] | number | NumberSearchSyntax;
}
```

For example :

```
expect((libInstance.filterTvSeries({
            additionalProperties: [
                {type: "number", name: "whateverFieldThatDoesn'tExist", value: "<50"},
                {type: "number", name: "AnotherField", value: undefined},
                {type: "number", name: "AnotherField2", value: "<=25"},
                {type: "number", name: "AnotherField3", value: ">25"},
                {type: "number", name: "AnotherField4", value: "==25"},
            ],
            season: ">=4",
        }))).toEqual(
            new Map(),
        );
```

Each one must first corresponds the following regex :

```
const validExpression = /^(==|>|<|>=|<=)(\d+)$/;
```

and then will be eval by this function :

```
function resolveExpression(property: string,
                           expressionObject: MediaScanTypes.NumberExpressionObject,
                           object: MediaScanTypes.TPN | MediaScanTypes.TPN_Extended): boolean {
    return eval(`${object[property]}${expressionObject.operator}${expressionObject.number}`);
}
```

I wonder what could be a more cleaner way to do that ... Please avoid easy answer like a switch case : I tested it but it was still slower in my tests than eval ...

Function constructor is for me the same thing than eval ..

Previous posts I read :
[Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function
...

Comment: What do you mean by cleaner? It seems pretty clean to me, you want faster?

Comment: Tslint and Eslint really hate eval and the code here could be mysterious for not advanced js programmers ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. implement functions for operators

   ops = {
       '>': (a, b) => a > b,
       '>=': (a, b) => a >= b
   };

   ops[expressionObject.operator](object[property], expressionObject.number)
2. if the expression is always valid as expected. then following should faster as no parsing.

   eval(`${object[property]}${expression}`)

Comment: Not a bad idea ^^ Just for fun, It could be interesting to do a benchemark for future readers :) (even if I know that eval is a monster ^^)

Answer (score 2):

You can have some mapping from `operator` to `function`

```
const ops = {'==':(a,b)=> a == b};
return ops[${expressionObject.operator}](${object[property]},${expressionObject.number})
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. aaron.xiao was the fastest one but no worry, you got your +1 :)