# Modified Secant method Javascript algorithm?

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-analysis, numerical-computing

I need your help to code this [New Secant Method](http://vixra.org/pdf/1405.0013v1.pdf) into Javascript.

The secant method uses two starting parameters, while this new method require only one starting parameter.

Thank you in advance.

---

Thank you for your answer [ed: comment], here is what i have tried, but it dosn't work :

```
<script>
    var x
    var pi = 3.141592653589793, e = 2.7182818284590452;

    function meth_sec() {
        with (Math) {
            f = "sin(x)-x/2"; a = 1; s = 1;
            f = prompt("your function f(x) = ", f)
            while (s >= 0) {
                a = eval(prompt("type the approximation. = ", a))                   
                x = a;                     
            }
        }
    } function iter() {
        with (Math) {
            y = eval(f)
            x = a + (abs(y)/2) - abs(y)*((y(a+abs(y/2)))/((y(a+abs(y/2)))-y)
            return x
        }
    }
    function sgn(y) { return (y > 0) - (y < 0) }

</script>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can help you fix code you’ve already written, but *we’re not here to write code for you*.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a variation of the Steffensen method, known for its close relation to Aitken's delta-squared process. It is less a secant method and more a Newton-like method, replacing the derivative `f'(x)` in `x_new = x-f(x)/f'(x)` with a divided difference approximation `(f(x+h(x))-f(x))/h(x)` resulting in the formula

```
x_new = x - (f(x)*h(x))/(f(x+h(x))-f(x))
      = x + h(x) + (f(x+h(x))*h(x))/(f(x+h(x))-f(x))
```

where `h(x)=O(f(x))` to force convergence towards the derivative as `x` approaches the root. Steffensen's method uses `h(x)=f(x)` while the cited method for some reason prefers `h(x)=abs(f(x))/2`. Neither is invariant under re-scaling of `f`, so there is no clear preference, there will be cases where either of the methods has a slight advantage.

By its relation to the Newton method one would expect quadratic convergence to simple roots, if there is convergence at all.

---

Your problem is that you use `y` both as value and as function. Apart from [the security problem of using `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+eval+is+evil) on user-supplied code snippets, you need to supply the `x` argument to supplement the function string, and then call the evaluation of the function string, and that for all the different points you want function values for.

A discussion on how to safely parse and evaluate expression strings is [Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2276021/3088138).