# String with addition and subtraction operator included, to evaluate the answer

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to get the result of a string with numbers and add/sub/multiply operators in between

> "1+5+6", "5-8+6", "1+5-8+9+4+6" ..etc

Comment: Please share with us what you have tried

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share what you have already tried. Did you already write some code and did you get stuck on a specific part? Please remember Stack Overflow is not a code writing service!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating a string as a mathematical expression in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript)

Comment: Try [math.js](https://mathjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Eval function :

```
eval(expression)
```

```js
console.log(eval("1+5-8+9+4+6"))
console.log(eval("1+5-8+9*6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function constructor/`eval` [*if it is safe to do so*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!) like so:

```js
const str = "1+5+6";
const res = (Function("return "+str))();
console.log(res); // 12
```

Or, instead, if you are only ever using the plus or minus operator in your string, I recommend you `.split()` your string into an array, and then use `.reduce()` to sum up each number like so:

```js
const str = "1+5+6-1+2";
const res = str.split(/([+-]\d+)/).reduce((sum, n) => sum+ +n, 0);
console.log(res); // 13
```

Comment: better `split(/(?:[+-])/)` this can deal with `+` and `-`

Comment: @Thomas well, I could do that, but that doesn't change the fact that reduce will always add (I think you have a similar problem with your answer)

Comment: no, because the `-` operator is now interpreted as a sign. `5-3` becomes `5+(-3)`

Comment: @Thomas `"1-5+8".split(/(?:[+-])/)` returns `["1", "5", "8"]`, not `["1", "-5", "+8"]`

Comment: sry, my bad. I meant `(?=)` not `(?:)`. Should have checked that.

Answer (score 0):

For such simple equations you don't need evil ([eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)), or its little brother, the Function constructor. These formulas can be parsed and evaluated with just a few commands.

```js
[
"1+5+6",
"5-8+6", "1+5-8+9+4+6"
].forEach(formula => {
  const result = formula.replace(/\s/g, "") // remove whitespace (just in case)
    .split(/(?=[+-])/) // split the string into numbers with their respective sign
    .map(Number)  // convert them into actual numbers
    .reduce((a,b) => a+b); // get the sum of the numbers (positive and negative)
    
  console.log(formula, "=", result);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) methods:

Below snippet will work for all **+/-** to any position.

```js
const val1= "1+5+6";
const val2= "1+5+6-3-4+5+6-3-5";
const val3= "-1+5+6-1-3-8+1";

let lastSign = '';

console.log(LetsSum(val1));
console.log(LetsSum(val2));
console.log(LetsSum(val3));

function LetsSum(val) {
  return val.split('').reduce((sum, ele, i) => {
    if(isNaN(parseInt(val[i]))) {
      lastSign = val[i];
    } else {
     sum = sum + +(lastSign+ele);
    }
  return sum;
  }, 0);
}
```