# is there a way to read and make joined calculations from a input text?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to read the value from an input text, and make all the math operations at once

I have gotten to calculate one operation such as 25+67 but I cannot make to read and split more complex operations such as 50+5*5, I do not know how to get the different values and make operations one by one, I have tried creating a loop using split everytime it finds something different than a number but it is not working

Where screen is the id of the input where you can write down all the numbers and operations you like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js/data.js"></script>
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mycalc">
        <form name="calculator" id="calculator" class="cuerpo">
            <h2 class="casio">CASIO</h2>
            <input type="text" name="screen" id="screen" readonly>
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="one" value="1" onclick="takeValue(1)">
                <input type="button" id="two" value="2" onclick="takeValue(2)">
                <input type="button" id="three" value="3" onclick="takeValue(3)">
                <input type="button" id="add" value="+" onclick="takeValue('+')">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="four" value="4" onclick="takeValue(4)">
                <input type="button" id="five" value="5" onclick="takeValue(5)">
                <input type="button" id="six" value="6" onclick="takeValue(6)">
                <input type="button" id="sus" value="-" onclick="takeValue('-')">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="seven" value="7" onclick="takeValue(7)">
                <input type="button" id="eight" value="8" onclick="takeValue(8)">
                <input type="button" id="nine" value="9" onclick="takeValue(9)">
                <input type="button" id="mul" value="*" onclick="takeValue('*')">
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" id="zero" value="0" onclick="takeValue(0)">
                <button type="button" id="clear" value="" onclick="clearInput()">AC</button>
                <input type="button" id="zero" value="="onclick="prueba()">
                <input type="button" id="div" value="/" onclick="takeValue('/')">


            </div>        
        </form> 
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function checkOperation(num1,num2, oper){
    let res;
    switch(oper){
        case "+":   
        res = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
        break;
        case "-":
        res = parseInt(num) + parseInt(num2);
        break;
        case "*":
        res = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
        break;
        case "/":
        res = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);  
        break;   
    }
    return res;         
}


function prueba(){   
    let actual = document.getElementById('screen').value;
    let arr = [];
    let res = 0;
    let res1 = 0;
    let temp;
    for(let i = 0; i < actual.length; i++){
        if(isNaN(actual[i])){
            let oper1 = actual[i];
            arr = actual.split(oper1);
            temp = arr[1];
            for(let j = 0; j < temp.length; j++){ 
                 if(isNaN(temp[j])){
                    let oper2 = temp[j];
                    let num1 = temp[0];
                    let num2 =  temp[1];
                    res = checkOperation(num1, num2, oper2)
                }   
            }
            res1 = checkOperation(parseInt(temp), res, oper1)
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('screen').value = res1;
}
```

Comment: Add your HTML as well.

Comment: If it's not a school assignment, you can use `eval()`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript

Comment: I have gone through the link you posted @OgnjenMarceta but I think my knowdledge does not get to understand it all at the moment,I thought that would be something simpler, I appreciate the comments anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JavaScript's [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function.

```js
const a = eval('25+67');

const b = eval('50+5*5');

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

However, do note that there are various [security risks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!) involved when using that function, hence you should be careful when it comes to using it on production code.

Comment: `eval(50+5*5)` does not evaluate anything. It should be `eval("50+5*5")`.

Comment: thanks I am aware of the eval function, the thing is that as I am new to coding I would like to do it myself instead of using the method eval so I can see the logic behind it

Comment: @frogatto how careless am I! I have editted it. Thanks!

Comment: @jesusfernandez ahh I see.. Cool. I don't exactly have a working solution at the top of my head, as I will need to spend some time cracking this problem, but I am guessing the first thing you should focus on should be the operator precedence.