# turn a string like "3+5/2" to a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a simple way of converting a sting like `<p>{"3+5/2"}</p>` or anything with only mathematical symbols to just `<p>{3+5/2}</p>` so it displays the result?

Comment: well there's always `eval` - but you should always think twice, or a hundred times, before using that. Where are you actually getting that string from in the first place?

Comment: You can use a [Wolfram Alpha API](https://products.wolframalpha.com/api/). You can send your formula there and get the result using AJAX calls.

Comment: I would be ‘very surprised’ if there are not suitable JS libraries, for parsing and evaluating various mathematical strings, which can be found with a little bit of earnest searching. As far as this question - searching on SO would reveal duplicates. See https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+evaluate+math+expression which finds questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/2276021/2864740

Comment: One of the many libs for this (and much more): [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/)

Comment: Yes, there is a simple way.

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks! I swear I did a search both in SO an Google. I guess I couldn't find the right terms to search.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. I'm going to go with [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/examples/expressions.js.html) and `math.evaluate`