# How do I take an equation from a string and solve it then put the answer back into a string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, equation

So i have a variable lets call that, equation. Which in this case is a string that means "5+10". How do write some code to solve that then put it back into a string to print back to the user?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help

```js
function Calculate(){
  var n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value
  var n2 = document.getElementById("n2").value
  var op = document.getElementById("op").value
  var ans = document.getElementById("ans")
  
  switch(op){
  case '+':
    ans.value = parseFloat(n1) + parseFloat(n2);
    break;
   case '-':
    ans.value = parseFloat(n1) - parseFloat(n2);
    break;
  case '*':
    ans.value = parseFloat(n1) * parseFloat(n2);
    break;
  case '/':
    ans.value = parseFloat(n1) / parseFloat(n2);
    break;
  default:
    ans.value = "Invalid Operator";
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><input type="number" id="n1" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="Enter 1st Number" minimum="0" value="0"  oninput="Calculate()" > 
<input type="string" max-length="1" id="op" size="5px" style="text-align:center;" placeholder="Operator"  oninput="Calculate()"> 
<input type="number" id="n2" oninput="Calculate()" placeholder="Enter 2nd Number" minimum="0" value="0" style="text-align:center;" ></p>
<input type="disabled" id="ans"  placeholder="Answer" style="text-align:center;" >
```