# How can I use a JS library without needing to add its name before each function

Tags: javascript, math

I am working with the built in Math library in js, and need a way to call its functions (eg:sin) without using `Math.` before the function name. Is there a way I can import it (without node) so this could be achieved, such that the following code would be valid? :

```js
var equation = "sin(x)";

eval(equation.replace("x","0")); // Should return 0
```

Comment: You're using `eval` so you may as well use `with`

Comment: @JaromandaX Two evils do not make a right ;)

Comment: Why are you string-replacing equations in the first place? You should write a function with parameters: `function equation(x) { return Math.sin(x); }`; or, well, `const equation = Math.sin` ( which hints at the answer you're asking for as well…).

Comment: I wish, however this is part of a graphing calculator running taylor series, It needs to work for any equation a user inputs, I can't make a function for every Mathematical equation.

Comment: Then use a dedicated parser for this, not `eval`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2276021/476

Comment: Ah, that would work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) keyword is for... I wouldn't recommend using it though, as it's generally discouraged, but if you want to, it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively add it to the Number prototype - it is not worse than eval

```js
Number.prototype.sin = function() { return Math.sin(this) };
const val = Math.PI / 2
console.log(val.sin())
```