How can you get the operator's precedence as a value in Javascript?
I am creating a calculator and need to determine precedence. My algorithm involves checking if the current operator input is a greater precedence than the previous ones entered.
Is there a function that takes an operator and returns its precedence value?
My current code involves matching the operator
if ( (item == "*" || item = "/") 
  && (compare == "+" || compare == "-")
  ){
  greaterPrecedence = True;
}


I do not believe this exists in Javascript. Given an arithmetic expression, JS knows the order of operations, but I assume you likely have more of a string or array of operators and values that you are parsing.

I suspect you would define and maintain this logic in your code.  JavaScript's documentation on operator precedence could certainly be your starting point.

You don't need the operator precedence in JS. You need to implement the operator precedence for your application. There is probably a large overlap but it's the difference between asking the Y or the X.

Also have a look at Parse arithmetic expression with javascript because that also shows how to implement precedence.

As I recall from my school days, operator order was enforced as a compiler rule

Also, if you are trying to do this as a learning experience, you might be better off creating a prefix or postfix calculator, because you don't need order of operations with those (search for either). Otherwise if this is for business: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276021/evaluating-a-string-as-a-mathematical-expression-in-javascript

You could build a lookup map of precedence to operators and then invert it and use a helper function to get the precedence for a given operator. You can default to -1.


// Lowest to highest
const operatorPrecedence = {
    1: ['||'],
    2: ['&&'],
    3: ['==', '!=', '===', '!=='],
    4: ['<', '>', '<=', '>='],
    5: ['+', '-'],
    6: ['*', '/', '%'],
    7: ['**']
};

// Inverted map of operator to precedence
const precedenceMap = Object.entries(operatorPrecedence)
  .reduce((outerMap, [precedence, operators]) =>
    operators.reduce((innerMap, operator) =>
      innerMap.set(operator, +precedence),
    outerMap
  ), new Map()
);

// Lookup function
const getPrecedence = (operator) => precedenceMap.get(operator) ?? -1;

// Loop over all known operators
Object.values(operatorPrecedence).flat().forEach(op => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ op, precedence: getPrecedence(op) }));
});
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }



